# Proving $a^2+b^2+c^2+\cdots+z^2<(a+b+c+\cdots+z)^2$

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

I know and can prove that, $a^2 + b^2 < (a+b)^2$ where $a > 0$ and $b > 0$

Now, how can I prove the generalization, i.e.

$$
a^2 + b^2+ c^2 + \cdots + z^2 < (a +b + c+ \cdots + z)^2
$$

What is the way to reach that conclusion from the above statement?

Comment: You need to restrict the domain.  It's false for $a=1, b=-1$ for example.

Comment: @lulu sorry, I just found the issue, fixed it. Can you look into the question again.

Comment: Looks inductiony.  $a^2+b^2+c^2 < (a+b)^2 + c^2 < (a+b+c)^2$

Comment: But if all the terms are $0$ the problem is trivial.  Just expand the expression on the right and cancel matcheing terms on the left.  What;'s left is strictly positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1,...,a_n\geq 0$. Then\begin{align}
(a_1+\cdots+a_n)^2&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ia_j\\
&=a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2+\sum_{i\neq j}a_ia_j\\
&\geq a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Induct.  For instance,
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 &= (a^2 + b^2) + c^2  \\
    &< (a+b)^2 + c^2  &  &  \text{base case on $a$, $b$}\\
    &< ((a+b)+c)^2  &  &  \text{base case on $a+b$, $c$}  \\
    &= (a+b+c)^2  \text{.}
\end{align*}

You should be able to see how to adapt this to a generic induction step...

Comment: Thanks. Though I have accepted the other answer, this one is more intuitive. +1